# ggplot to generate the stacked bar chart with two y axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, seurat

I try to copy the style of stacked bar chart like below by a seurat object metadata.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twsIf.png)
[image]

Here is the code I try and generate like below.

```
p1 <- ggplot(meta_data, aes(y = interaction (cohort, factor(meta_data$patient_ID,levels = rev(patient_ID_reorder)), sep = " "),  
                      fill =  celltype), group = 1) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill")+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
         axis.text.x = element_blank(),
         axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
         axis.title.y=element_blank(),
         axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
         panel.background = element_blank()
        )+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")+
  ggtitle("Cell type proporation") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfWb5.png)
[image]
I try facet_wrap(~ cohort), which generate a panel like below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMgNx.png)

[image]
However, I don't know how to use different colored rectangles to replace "mono" and "combo" and increase the spaces between "mono" and "combo".

Any help is appriciated!

I have tried all methods I searched but failed.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is best to show images in the question itself as the links may become invalid in future.

Comment: It will also be useful if you can post a sample of your data (`meta_data`) here for others to try the code on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach to get you close to your desired result using `ggh4x::facet_nested` for nested facet, `ggnewscale::new_scale_fill` for a second fill scale and `patchwork` to add the column labels. Finally, to the colored bars for `cohort` I use a `geom_col` and add the axis text via a `geom_text`.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
meta_data <- data.frame(
  patient_ID = paste0("P", seq(20)),
  cohort = c(rep("mono", 3), rep("combo", 3), rep("mono", 7), rep("combo", 7)),
  celltype = rep(letters[1:5], each = 20),
  type = c(rep("pre", 6), rep("post", 14))
)

set.seed(123)

meta_data <- meta_data[sample(nrow(meta_data), 1000, replace = TRUE), ]

library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

meta_data$type <- factor(meta_data$type, c("pre", "post"))

p1 <- ggplot(meta_data, aes(
  y = patient_ID
)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = celltype), position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1") +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_col(data = dplyr::distinct(meta_data, patient_ID, cohort, type), aes(x = -.3, fill = cohort), width = .9) +
  geom_col(data = dplyr::distinct(meta_data, patient_ID, cohort, type), aes(x = -.15), fill = "white", color = "white") +
  geom_text(data = dplyr::distinct(meta_data, patient_ID, cohort, type), aes(x = -.075, label = patient_ID)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  facet_nested(type + cohort ~ .,
    scale = "free_y", space = "free_y",
    strip = strip_nested(
      by_layer_y = TRUE,
      background_y = list(element_rect(), element_blank()),
      text_y = list(element_text(), element_blank())
    )
  )

p2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_text(data = data.frame(
    y = 21,
    x = c(-.225, -0.075, .5),
    label = c("Cohort", "ID", "Cell type proporation")
  ), aes(x = x, y = y, label = label), fontface = "bold") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(-.3, 1)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")

library(patchwork)

p2 + p1 & plot_layout(heights = c(1, 20)) &
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank()
  ) &
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this excellent coding!!!! If I want to change font size of "cohort", "ID", "Cell type proporation" ? I tried to add size information in the geom_text layer, but failed.

Comment: In `p2` try e.g. `geom_text(..., size = 8)`. That will approx. double the font size of the column labels.